# IntelliJ community edition not finding existing dependency

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.1 Community edition on Windows 7 and its complaining about Dependencies even if it's there. Please refer the following screenshot:

[image]

```
<dependency>
          <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
          <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
          <version>${oracle.jdbc.version}</version>       
</dependency>
```

Here is the screenshot of the file present inside the `.m2` folder (full path : `D:\Users\myusername\.m2\repository\com\oracle\ojdbc7\12.1.0.1`

Do I need to do something like [install:install-file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) by going to the `12.1.0.1` folder from windows command ?

The oracle website has been flaky for the past two weeks ( I have confirmed with few other people as well where they faced the same issue) where I am not able to download the `ojdbc7.jar` from [their website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html). Hence, I have downloaded the file from the server using FileZilla and placed it manually in the `12.1.0.1` folder, could this be creating problem?

[image]

Comment: can you try reimporting the jars in maven and if doesn't work clear the intelliJ cache and try again

Comment: I tried `Reimport All Maven Projects` option and then `Invalidate Caches and Restart` , still I see same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another repository.

```
<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
  <id>maven.oracle.com</id>
   <url>https://maven.oracle.com</url>
 </pluginRepository>
```

Look at http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/core/MAVEN/config_maven_repo.htm#MAVEN9010

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Actually, the above settings works fine on the server and hence I was not trying to make changes to `pom.xml` locally as well so that when I push the code to github, it remains same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes acoording to that you can use maven repositery
https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=ojdbc7 you can refer this maven repositery